# Specifying a file for VirtualShape in SpatiaLite

Tags: spatialite, windows, file-path

I'm <del>fairly</del> very new to spatialite, and am stuck on something very basic.

I'm creating a virtual table from a shapefile using virtualshape. This works fine when the shapefiles are in the same folder as spatialite.exe.

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING VirtualShape(test, CP1252, 28356);`

I can't figure out how to specify an absolute path ie `C:\1. Project Data\1814\test`

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING VirtualShape("C:\1. Project Data\1814\test", CP1252, 28356);`

Fails.

What's the syntax that's required here?

Comment: Very embarrassing, I had the filename incorrect (was pointing at mapinfo files instead of shapefiles). I literally spent hours trying to get this command to work.

Comment: Matthew, I'm closing this question since it turns out that there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're at least missing the closing "

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test USING VirtualShape("C:\1. Project Data\1814\test", CP1252, 28356);
```

Comment: apologies, typo in the question - not the command

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax appears to be correct. Check your path.

One way to debug this is to use [spatialite-gui](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/binaries.html) to create the the VirtualShape. If it works, right click the table name and select 'Show CREATE Statement'. Copy that and use it.

Comment: This only shows a statement of the form `CREATE TABLE "Test"("PK_UID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"HEIGHT" DOUBLE,
"RADIUS" DOUBLE,
Geometry BLOB)`

Comment: That's not a virtual shapefile. Most likely, you already have a table named test. Rename or drop the table "test" and try again. Make sure you're not importing the shapefile instead of creating a virtual one.